# How do I install Groovy 3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, groovy

sudo apt-get install groovy provides me with:

`groovy -v`

`Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.8.0_150`

However, this version of Groovy is very old. How do I get the newest one installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use SDKMAN to install it:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

And then run the install command for Groovy:

```
sdk install groovy
```

You will find further information on the [SDKMAN website](http://sdkman.io/index.html).

Comment: it's downloading 2.4.13

Comment: in addition to the answer above, since you specifically want version 3.0, `sdk list groovy` should provide you with the list of available versions. so you can simply install it with `sdk install groovy 3.0.0-alpha-1`

Comment: groovy is in alpha state, so not officially released. But you can use `sdk list groovy`, to see which versions you can install.

Comment: @geneqew It works!! Thanks a lot. I've installed groovy 3.0.0